# (Swift) How would one check if a specific index of an array was empty?

Tags: swift

```
var array:[Int] = []
var index = 5

if array[index] == nil {
    array[index] = 1
}
```

Currently Xcode states that an int can not take the value of nil. So this code doesn't work. Is there any way to produce the same effect or verifying if a specific index is empty?

Comment: You would have to declare the array as `array:[Int?]` but you also need to check the array size so that you don't get a bounds overflow

Answer (score 1):

If the array can hold `nil` values, then its type must be an `optional` - as such:

```
var array:[Int?] = []
```

In general, when accessing an array based on an index you need to confirm that the index is in range.  You might extend Array with

```
extension Array {
  func ref (i:Index) -> Element? {
    return i < count ? self[i] : nil
  }
}
```

and then use as:

```
array.ref(i)
```

[Note: this will confound `nil` as 'out of range' with `nil` as 'value in optional array']

Answer (score 0):

Declaring the property as:

```
var array:[Int] = []
```

the array property itself can be empty (no values) - as it is when you declare it as you did above, but it cannot contain nil values, so a check for nil shouldn't be necessary.

If you are checking to see if the array is empty, calling array.isEmpty, or checking array.count > 0 should do the trick.

If you need to store empty (non-initialized Int's/nil) in the array, then the array would be declared as:

```
var array:[Int?] = []
```

in which case the array could hold integers, or nil values.  In this case you would need to safely unwrap the optional prior to using it, such as:

```
var array:[Int?] = [1, 2, nil, 4]    
for item in array {
      if let item = item {
        print("item is \(item)")
      } else {
        print("item is nil")
      }
    }

    //    item is 1
    //    item is 2
    //    item is nil
    //    item is 4
```